# How to download unread email attachment using Exchange web service in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Server 2007 SP3

and I am able to connect exchange web service using following code

```
ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
esb.RequestServerVersionValue = new RequestServerVersion();
esb.RequestServerVersionValue.Version = ExchangeVersionType.Exchange2007_SP1;
esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<user_id>", "<password>", "<domain>");
esb.Url = @"https://<server_fqdn>/ews/Exchange.asmx";
```

I am looking for code to download unread attachment.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 5):

I have found this:

```
private static void ProcessItems(ExchangeService exchangeService)
{
    var offset = 0;
    const int pageSize = 100;

    FindItemsResults<Item> result;

    do
    {
        var view = new ItemView(pageSize, offset)
        {
            SearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false)
        };

        result = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            ProcessItem(item);
        }

        offset += pageSize;
    } while (result.MoreAvailable);
}
```

then from the method `ProcessItem` you do whatever you want to do like download attachments and so on...

source: [Processing items in an Exchange folder using EWS Managed API](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2009/06/07/Processing-items-in-an-Exchange-folder-using-EWS-Managed-API.aspx)